# Segue in MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification does no fire till second time

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, segue

Just upgraded a project from iOS5 to iOS7. For a reason I can not fathom the video now plays twice before the segue works

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"LogoVC viewDidAppear");

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"start_sting_logo_resolve" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController];

    // no moviecontrolls
    moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    moviePlayerController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [moviePlayerController play];
}


#pragma mark - Video methods


- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"moviePlaybackComplete");
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [moviePlayerController release];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToScroller" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"preformed performSegueWithIdentifier");
}
```

The view loads twice according to the log

```
2014-07-01 14:25:17.872 Appname[1620:60b] LogoVC viewDidAppear
2014-07-01 14:25:31.745 Appname[1620:60b] moviePlaybackComplete
2014-07-01 14:25:31.766 Appname[1620:60b] LogoVC viewDidAppear
2014-07-01 14:25:31.965 Appname[1620:60b] preformed performSegueWithIdentifier
2014-07-01 14:25:44.089 Appname[1620:60b] moviePlaybackComplete
2014-07-01 14:25:44.124 Appname[1620:60b] preformed performSegueWithIdentifier
2014-07-01 14:25:44.190 Appname[1620:60b] ScrollerVC viewDidLoad
```

The video file is local.

MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is firing, but instead of the segue being performed, the viewcontroller seems to reload, and only the segue only woks the second time MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification is called.

It's custom segue if that makes any difference

```
#import "JBCustomSegue.h"

@implementation JBCustomSegue

- (void) perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    int orient = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (orient==3){
        // Orient for Landscape Right 4
        [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                        animations:^{[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];} completion:NULL];


    } else if (orient==4) {
        // Orient for Landscape Left 3
        [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                        animations:^{[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];} completion:NULL];
    } else {
        // Orient for Landscape Right 4
        [UIView transitionWithView:src.navigationController.view duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                        animations:^{[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];} completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

The thing is this didn't happen per-iOS7

Comment: It could be related to your second instance of MPMoviePlayerController in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: How do you mean - second instance?

Comment: If this is your MPMoviePlayerController.m, and you are using storyboard, you are creating a new instance of the MoviePlayerController in your ViewDidAppear. From what I see, but I could be incorrect.

Comment: The story board consists of 'LogoVC - Original View' -> 'View', 'Navigation Item'. No other elements

Comment: try changing the notification object to self in the moviePlaybackComplete. It still seems like a new instance is getting created and it could be related to your removeFromSuperview also.

Comment: Failed to call the notification

Comment: Ok, sorry I could not help.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be `_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;`

I added the screen dimensions instead with `[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];`

```
NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"start_sting_logo_resolve" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

_moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayerController];

// no moviecontrolls
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

[_moviePlayerController.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayerController.view];

//_moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
_moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
_moviePlayerController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[_moviePlayerController play];
```

Comment: Oh good find. You can instead just take it out of full screen right before you call removeFromSuperview.